# Need help with understanding $f^{-1}$ when $f$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

I was asked to prove the following proposition

4.14 Proposition Let: $f: G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphisms between groups $G$ and $H$.

(a) if $U$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $f(U)$ is a subgroup of $H$.
(b) if $V$ is a subgroup of $H$ then $f^{-1}(V)$ is a subgroup of $G$

I already proved part (a) and I am uploading my proof later today for feedback. My problem is in part (b). We don't know anything about $f^{-}1$. I don't know if $f$ being homomorphic implies $f^{-1}$ is homormorphic. if that's true then why is it true?. The proof would be the same if $f^{-1}$ is homomorphic

Comment: The notation $f^{-1}(V)$ does not mean applying the function $f^{-1}$ to $V$, since $f$ need not be invertible. It just means the preimage of $V$ under $f$.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is here seen as something more basic, namely as a pure function from the subsets (not even subgroups) of $H$ to subsets of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if a group homomorphism $f:G\to H$ has an inverse function $f^{-1}$, then $f^{-1}$ is automatically a group homomorphism too. Given any two $h_1, h_2\in H$, we can consider the two elements $f^{-1}(h_1)$ and $f^{-1}(h_2)$ in the condition for $f$ being a homomorphism and get
$$ f\bigl(f^{-1}(h_1)*f^{-1}(h_2)\bigr) = f(f^{-1}(h_1))*(f(f^{-1}(h_2)) = h_1 * h_2 $$
Taking $f^{-1}$ on both sides of this yields
$$ f^{-1}(h_1)*f^{-1}(h_2) = f^{-1}(h_1*h_2) $$
so $f^{-1}$ is a homomorphism.

---

But this is not really relevant for your exercise, because here the notation $f^{-1}(V)$ does not mean to apply an inverse function, but merely to take a *preimage*. By definition,
$$ f^{-1}(V) \text{ means } \{ g\in G \mid f(g)\in V \} $$